# Uploading image with one to one relationship laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, one-to-one

I am having some difficulty doing this problem, what I want to do is to upload an image to my database where this image must have a user_id equal to the id of the personal_information table.

This is what I am making:  when logging in, I am an admin and I can see all the users name which are all taken from the user_information table, and I can click on their name to see their information and also I can upload pictures so that I know how they look like.

This is what it look like inside my view when I click on the person name:
[image]

Current code that I have:

test.blade.php (shown based on screenshot)

```
@foreach ($data as $object)
    <b>Name: </b>{{ $object->Name }}<br><br>
 <a href="{{ url('/user/show/'.$object->id.'/edit') }}">Edit</a><br>

 @foreach($data3 as $currentUser)
<a href="{!! route('user.upload.image', ['user'=>$currentUser->user_id])  !!}">
    <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class ="fa fa-plus"></i>Upload Images</button>
</a>
@endforeach


@endforeach
```

CreateController (controller for uploading image and also for upload page)

```
public function create1(personal_info $user){
     return view('create1')->withUser($user);

public function store1(Request $request){

   $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

   if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $image = $request->file('file');
        $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $size = $image->getClientSize();
        $id = $request->user_id;
        $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $name);

        $userImage = new UserImage;
        $personal_info = new personal_info;
        $userImage->name = $name;
        $userImage->size = $size;
        $user= personal_info::find($id);
         $user->UserImages()->save($userImage);
}
       return redirect('/home');
    }
public function test($id){
   $user = personal_info::where('id',$id)->first();
  return view('create1', compact('user'));
}
}
```

Create1.blade.php (upload page)

```
       <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/userUpload')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        {{  csrf_field()  }}
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$user->id()}}">

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="imageInput" class="control-label col-sm-3">Upload Image</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="file" name="file">

        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6-offset-2">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
            </div>
          </div>
          </form>
```

UserImage model:

```
class UserImage extends Eloquent
{
   protected $fillable = array('name','size','user_id');
    public function personal_infos() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\personal_info', 'user_id', 'id');
    }  
}
```

personal_info model:

```
class personal_info extends Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = array('Name');
    protected $table = 'personal_infos';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

        public function UserImages() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserImage','user_id');
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/userUpload/{id}/create1','CreateController@create1')->name('user.upload.iamge');
Route::post('/userUpload','CreateController@store1');
Route::get('/user/showImage/{id}', 'HomeController@Insert')->name("image");
Route::post('/userUpload/create1', 'CreateController@test');
```

Getting this error:
[image]

Comment: I think the code above already does that. Do you have any errors?

Comment: The above code did do all this but what I want is to make so that there won't be any need for adding of new data first then the upload button appear. Error facing right now is this "Route [user.upload.image] not defined." Right now still googling on how to solve it

Comment: I just want to make the UserImage to be a one to one relationship with the personal_info table

Comment: so does that mean `$object->id` can be the `$currentUser->id` ?

Comment: They should be different, wait I think the should be this $currentUser->user_id

Comment: $object-> id is the id from the personal_info table while $currentUser->id is the id from the UserImage table, so if I were to change to this "$currentUser->user_id " there should be a relationship happening but it doesn't work. You understand what I mean?

Comment: but `$object->id` refers to the `user_id` or the `UserImages` right?

Comment: Yup @NorrisOduro

Comment: good... let me post an answer then :)

Comment: I just want to make sure there is a relationship between this 2 table when I upload the image and the upload button must always be there and not based on the data inside database. So that when I post the image it should be easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Upload` button only displays when the `$data3` is not empty. to display it even when its empty, use a conditional to check if its empty and do something else if its not. like this:

```
@foreach ($data as $object)
    <b>Name: </b>{{ $object->Name }}<br><br>
 <a href="{{ url('/user/show/'.$object->id.'/edit') }}">Edit</a><br>

  @if($data3->count())
 @foreach($data3 as $currentUser)
<a href="{!! route('user.upload.image', ['id'=>$currentUser->user_id])  !!}">
    <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class ="fa fa-plus"></i>Upload Images</button>
</a>
@endforeach
@else
 <a href="{!! route('user.upload.image', ['id'=>$object->id])  !!}">
    <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class ="fa fa-plus"></i>Upload Images</button>
@endif    

@endforeach
```

The relationships have already been set in the controller. All you need is to display the button and the controllers would handle the rest

**EDIT**

You are getting the error because your route name is `'user.upload.iamge'` instead of `'user.upload.image'`

Comment: Currently I keep getting this error "Route [user.upload.image] not defined." , I checked that people said it might be because of similar routes but I don't think there is

Comment: change this from `['user'=>$currentUser->user_id]` to `['id'=>$currentUser->user_id]`

Comment: and this from `['user'=>$object->id]` to `['id'=>$object->id]`

Comment: Same result, I just now tried changing the route '/userUpload/{id}/create1' to '/userUpload/{user}/create1' also doesn't work

Comment: does this happen because of the answer? try reverting back to how it was previously

Comment: Could it be the form part or the hidden part in create1.blade.php (upload page)

Comment: This happen after using your answer from previous question, it was okay for a while then suddenly it became like this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157540/discussion-between-blastme-and-norris-oduro).

Comment: sorry to disturb you again but how do I print out the image? I tried using this code inside the for loop but doesn't work, "<img src="{{ asset('public/images/' . $currentUser->name ) }}">" @NorrisOduro

Comment: You need to append the image extension to the image name in your controller

Comment: So I need to put the name of the image? Something like hello.jpg? Is there anything like changing it into something like this $filename instead of putting the name of the file

Comment: dont forget to paste the link here

Comment: Sure hold on a minute

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46950583/trouble-getting-the-image-out-from-public-folder-with-a-one-to-one-relationship here is the link to the next question, thank you so much for helping me