# Trouble getting the image out from public folder with a one-to-one relationship

Tags: php, laravel, one-to-one

I am having some trouble getting the image from the public folder where in the database, I have `UserImage` table and `personal_info` table and they are connected together in a one to one relationship. I have tried using this but it just return me blank results.

Here are the codes:

**HomeController:**

```
public function getInfo($id) {
    $data = personal_info::where('id', $id)->get();
    $data3 = UserImage::where('user_id', $id)->get();
    return view('test',compact('data', 'data3'));
```

**test.blade.php** *(where I show the image)*

```
@foreach ($data as $object)
    <b>Name: </b>{{ $object->Name }}<br><br>
    @foreach ($data3 as $currentUser)
    <img src="{{ asset('public/images/' . $currentUser->name ) }}">
    @endforeach
    @if ($data3->count())
        @foreach ($data3 as $currentUser)
        <a href="{!! route('user.upload.image', ['id' => $currentUser->user_id]) !!}">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class ="fa fa-plus"></i>Upload Images
            </button>
        </a>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <a href="{!! route('user.upload.image', ['id' => $object->id]) !!}">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class ="fa fa-plus"></i>Upload Images
        </button>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

**Create1Controller:**

```
public function store1(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $image = $request->file('file');
        $name  = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $size  = $image->getClientSize();
        $id    = $request->user_id;

        $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $name);

        $userImage = new UserImage;
        $personal_info = new personal_info;
        $userImage->name = $name;
        $userImage->size = $size;
        $user = personal_info::find($id);
        $user->UserImages()->save($userImage);
    }
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Comment: dd `$currentUser->name` inside the foreach lets see

Comment: Ok hold on a min

Comment: Wait a min, I thought we can't dd inside a view file? I thought it can only be done in a controller

Comment: {{dd($currentUser->name)}}

Comment: It return this ""58832_300x300.jpg""

Comment: which is the correct image name

Comment: I think you should rename the images before you save them...  Else you will get name collisions

Comment: @blastme Have you created the symbolic link `php artisan storage:link` [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem)

Comment: Where do you save the uploaded files?

Comment: Inside my public storage, but the images names will be different I think since I will be taking the images through mobile device in the future, so when I take a photo and upload it, it will always be different @NorrisOduro

Comment: @linktoahref I don't think I might be using that

Comment: @blastme paste your controller code in the question

Comment: Done @NorrisOduro

Comment: Replace `{{ asset('public/images/' . $currentUser->name ) }}` with `{{ url('images/' . $currentUser->name ) }}`

Comment: Oh my god it work, tks a lot, but seeing the code like this does it require internet access for it? Since it put a URL there and also could you post your answer? @Linktoahref

Comment: @linktoahref post as an answer :)

Comment: Thanks for your help also, really appreciate it :) @NorrisOduro

Comment: @blastme you're always welcome .. i think you should consider using the `storage` too

Comment: But what is the difference, I saw people also doing it but why? @NorrisOduro

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem

Comment: @NorrisOduro thank you so much for the resource, will read it later :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not saving your assets into storage and saving into your public directory you could use the [`url()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-url) method instead. If you need to stick with [`asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-asset) you need to create a symlink from the storage directory to the public directory which is explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem), and use the storage directory to save your assets.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, there is no relation between saved image name and the $currentUser->name

Can you show your code you use to save the image? There you have to save the image with current user name.

The error here: `$image->move($destinationPath, $name);`

Comment: What is wrong with it? I just move it into my public storage?

Comment: yes that is the error, save with user name instead of $image->getClientOriginalName()

Comment: Then wouldn't the image be saved into database?

Comment: another solution, u can use url('images/' . $currentUser->name ) instead of your asset

Comment: Oh it ok the question have been solved, thank you so much for your help as well :)